# How can lists share structure in ways that are impossible for arrays in Common Lisp?

Tags: arrays, list, common-lisp

I am trying to learn Common Lisp with the book *Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to Symbolic Computation*. In chapter 13 (the penultimate one), the book covers arrays.

Thus, the author makes a contrast between list and arrays. He says:

> Because storage in arrays is contiguous, we can access each element of
> an array as fast as any other element. With lists, we have to follow a
> chain of pointers to get from one cons cell to the next, so depending
> on the length of the list, it can take much, much longer to access the
> last element than the first. Efficient access is the prime advantage
> arrays have over lists. Another advantage is that in most
> implementations, an array uses only half as much memory as a list of
> equal length. But lists also have some advantages over arrays. Lists
> of arbitrary length are easily built up element by element, either
> recursively or iteratively. It is not as easy to grow an array one
> element at a time. Another advantage of lists is that they can share
> structure in ways that are impossible for arrays, but we won’t get
> into the details of that in this book.

I understand all comments but the last intentionally cryptic one:

> Another advantage of lists is that they can share structure in ways
> that are impossible for arrays, but we won’t get into the details of
> that in this book.

What exactly would be the **share of structure** which is possible in the list's data structure but impossible in arrays?

Could someone give me an example to illustrate this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g., create two lists that share the tail:

```lisp
(defparameter *l1* (list 1 2 3))
(defparameter *l2* (cons 0 (cdr *l1*))) ; (0 2 3)
```

Now, `(eq (cdr *l1*) (cdr *l2*))` is `t`, and modifying one list can modify the other:

```lisp
(setf (second *l1*) 10)
; now *l1* is (1 10 3)
; and *l2* is (0 10 3)
```

Note that arrays [*can*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_d.htm#displaced_array) share structure too:

```lisp
(defparameter *a1* (make-array 10 :initial-contents (loop for i from 1 to 10 collect i)))
; now *A1* is #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
(defparameter *a2* (make-array '(2 3) :displaced-to *a1* :displaced-index-offset 3))
; now *A2* refers to a part of *A1*: #2A((4 5 6) (7 8 9))
```

Now, modifying `*a1*` also modifies `*a2*`:

```lisp
(setf (aref *a1* 6) 123)
; now *a1* is #(1 2 3 4 5 6 123 8 9 10)
; and *a2* is  #2A((4 5 6) (123 8 9))
```

The difference here between lists and arrays is in the *way* structure is shared: lists can share *tails* while arrays can share *contiguous memory segments*.

Comment: In fact, array displacement is a little *more* powerful than list sharing. Lists can only share tails, but displaced arrays can share any subsequence, and change the shape.

Comment: But the displaced array must be the entire shared part.